# Horizontal scroll swipe in a webview component inside Pageviewer in Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a set of **Viewpagers** which i have implemented using the PageAdapters. In some of the Pages in the Pageviewer, i have webviews. The webviews has horizontal scrollers inside(Something similar to a Range selecter). When i try to drag some range, the page also gets swiped.

What exactly i need help is when i make any operation on  a particular element/component  in a webview, how can i avoid the pageviewer swiping and the operation inside the webview is accomplished.

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend the Webview widget and override two methods as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event)
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent p_event)
{
    if (p_event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && getParent() != null)
    {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(p_event);
}
```